# How do I erase an image on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I have a html5 canvas where you can erase the blur on top of an image. I would like to replace the blur with another image. I would like the end result to be once you erase the top image the bottom image will appear below it. I have been using an easeljs demo as a template.

http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/alphamask

I feel like what I need to edit is in the html page script but it might be much deeper than that.

([Full code can be viewed here](http://pastebin.com/NKZXyHiW))

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="960" height="400"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var stage;
var isDrawing;
var drawingCanvas;
var oldPt;
var oldMidPt;
var displayCanvas;
var image;
var bitmap;
var maskFilter;
var cursor;
var text;
var blur;

function init() {
    if (window.top != window) {
        document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById("loader").className = "loader";

    image = new Image();
    image.onload = handleComplete;
    image.src = "images/summer.jpg";

    stage = new createjs.Stage("testCanvas");
    text = new createjs.Text("Loading...", "20px Arial", "#999999");
            text.set({x:stage.canvas.width/2, y:stage.canvas.height-80});
    text.textAlign = "center";
}

function handleComplete() {
    document.getElementById("loader").className = "";
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
    stage.enableMouseOver();

    stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", handleMouseDown);
    stage.addEventListener("stagemouseup", handleMouseUp);
    stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove", handleMouseMove);
    drawingCanvas = new createjs.Shape();
    bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);

    blur = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
    blur.filters = [new createjs.BoxBlurFilter(15,15,2)];
    blur.cache(0,0,960,400);
    blur.alpha = .5;

    text.text = "Click and Drag to Reveal the Image.";

    stage.addChild(blur, text, bitmap);
    updateCacheImage(false);

    cursor = new createjs.Shape(new     createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#FFFFFF").drawCircle(0,0,20));
    cursor.cursor = "pointer";

    stage.addChild(cursor);
}

function handleMouseDown(event) {
    oldPt = new createjs.Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
    oldMidPt = oldPt;

    isDrawing = true;
}

function handleMouseMove(event) {
    cursor.x = stage.mouseX;
    cursor.y = stage.mouseY;

    if (!isDrawing) {
        stage.update();
        return;
    }

    var midPoint = new createjs.Point(oldPt.x + stage.mouseX>>1, oldPt.y+stage.mouseY>>1);

            drawingCanvas.graphics.setStrokeStyle(40, "round", "round")
                .beginStroke("rgba(0,0,0,0.15)")
                .moveTo(midPoint.x, midPoint.y)
                .curveTo(oldPt.x, oldPt.y, oldMidPt.x, oldMidPt.y);

    oldPt.x = stage.mouseX;
    oldPt.y = stage.mouseY;

    oldMidPt.x = midPoint.x;
    oldMidPt.y = midPoint.y;

    updateCacheImage(true);

}

function handleMouseUp(event) {
    updateCacheImage(true);
    isDrawing = false;
}

function updateCacheImage(update) {
    if (update) {
        drawingCanvas.updateCache(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    } else {
        drawingCanvas.cache(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    }

    maskFilter = new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(drawingCanvas.cacheCanvas);

    bitmap.filters = [maskFilter];
    if (update) {
        bitmap.updateCache(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    } else {
        bitmap.cache(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    }

    stage.update();
}
```

Comment: 1) Layer two images, erase from top. (i.e. `<canvas>` over `<img>`) or 2) Build an image mask during painting and use that with global composite modes. (HINT: 1 is much easier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to replace the blur-image, you have to change the following parts:

Add this after the loading of the first image:

```
image.src = "images/summer.jpg";
// add new part
image2 = new Image();
image2.onload = handleComplete;
image2.src = "images/your_newImage.jpg";
```

In the `handleComplete()` you now wait for 2 images to be loaded, so you add this:

```
function handleComplete() {
    loaded++; // and initialize this variable in the very top with: var loaded = 0;
    if ( window.loaded < 2 ) return;
    //... other stull
```

and finally you change the following lines:

```
// old
blur = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
blur.filters = [new createjs.BoxBlurFilter(15,15,2)];
blur.cache(0,0,960,400);
blur.alpha = .5;

// new
blur = new createjs.Bitmap(image2);
```

This should now replace the blurred image with your desired image, it's not the best way, but it should get you there. I recommend you to start with some tutorial if you are planing to do more "deeper" stuff ;)

Comment: I have gotten this to work, thank you. I am totally willing to study up on JavaScript. I have tried to learn from a book I own about three times with very little success. Do you know of any good tutorial sites olson?

Comment: It depends on what you want you want to do, if you want to utilize the canvas, I'd suggest you pick a framework (like you did with EaselJS) and start by learning that, an example is 'Instant EaselJS Starter [Instant]' by Packt Publishing, but there are also many free tutorials out there, just depends on what you want to do. And of course there are many other frameworks as well, like paper.js or caat.js - If the answer solved your problem, can you accept it as the solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

a common, though kinda janky, way is to re-size your canvas real quick.  so changing your `<canvas>` elements `width` and `height` attributes.  This will erase everything in your canvas.

Once that is done, reset it back to what you want it to be right away, and redraw the bottom image.

As I said this method is kinda sketchy but it does get the job done.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I understand how to change my height and width. Then I change it back? I don't see how this will do anything. How do I redraw the bottom image? Wouldn't the blur still be on the canvas. I want to replace the blur with an image that erases instead of the blur.

Comment: Yes, then you change it back.  The canvas element automatically erases all contained content on resize of the element.  Its just its nature.  
However you drew the bottom image in the first place, do that again

Comment: I re-sized the canvas in the html coding and this line of javascript text.set({x:stage.canvas.width/2, y:stage.canvas.height-80});/, then refreshed the page. Exactly as I thought the canvas changed size and nothing else happened. I changed the canvas size back to the original size and and the canvas went back to that size. As for redrawing the image, I did not write this code to begin with and I am very limited with javascript skills. This code was borrowed from a demo at easeljs which I was able to make work on my own. Now I am trying to tweak it for a specific purpose. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Refreshing the page wont work.  That just requests the same page again.  You will have to program it into a javascript function.  Since your javascript skill is limited I would still recommend bushing up on it.  In the meantime, take a look at this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431140/remove-a-previous-stroke-make-a-temporary-line-javascript-html5

Its a question I'd asked a while ago and the accepted answer should help you.